# Does defining all new syntaxes hurt performance in Scheme, Racket?

Tags: performance, compilation, binary, scheme, racket

Im creating a new lang with Racket define-syntax-parser. A lot of new syntaxes and even replacing fundamental forms.

I intend to use the new lang in production but dont know whether too many new syntaxes hurt performance.

Should I compile to binary or sort of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL; DR: No performance penalty

The syntax you intrduce gets expanded at macro expansion time. This means that if you do `raco make` it would have replaced all the use of macros with their expanded forms.

Sometimes when making features your expanded code might be more complex than how you would have written the code initially. This also might be removed by the jit compiler as it would with other unoptimized code.

Sometimes your feature required more complexity that cannot be reduced to it's simplest form. In this case you might have a performance loss.

As an example would be overriding `#%app` to do array and list access where you normally would do `(vector-ref vec 3)` where the syntax `(vec 3)` can mean both array access and application. The expansion might become `(if (racket:#%app vector? vec) (racket:#%app vector-ref vec 3) (racket:#%app vec 3))` and if the system cannot conclude that it is not `vector?` it will do the test on every application. If one would repurpose `[` and `]` such that they just are array access `[vec 5]` can easily be turned into `(vector-ref vec 3)` without `(vec 5)` having performance hits, but that also means the syntax tells you what it is and is less general.

Comment: I think you meant `#%app` rather than `%top`.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase I did indeed. Thanks